# How to build both vc9 and vc10 version of Boost on one machine?

Tags: c++, boost

I have both vc9 and vc10 installed.
I can build vc10 Boost successfully, but I can't build vc9 version.
I've tried "bootstrap.bat vc9", and it did not help.
The Boost is 1.51.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer [Boost.Build V2 User Manual](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html)

One of possible variants is:

```
booststrap.bat
b2 --build-type=complete toolset=msvc-9.0,msvc-10.0 address-model=64 variant=debug,release threading=multi link=static
```

P.S. 1.52 version of Boost is released today

Comment: Bad luck. Just finished my work with 1.51, and have to do it again!